# Remove a view with a plugin inside using Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a code to make a view of a model who starts a plugin when `#addHome`is clicked. The plugin modify a  tag:

```
<select id="sel">
    <option value="1">ON</option>
    <option value="0">OFF</option>
</select>
```

Backbone.js code:

```
var Contents = Backbone.View.extend({       
    events: {
            "click #addHome": "addContent1", "click #addContact": "addContent2"
    },
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this); 
        this.model = new ContentCollection();
        this.model.on("add", this.contentAdded);
    },                  
    addContent1: function(event) {
        this.model.add({ modelName: "home"});
        //Plugin:
        $('select').switchify().data('switch').bind('switch:slide', function(e,type){       
            //Do something
        });     
    }, 
    addContent2: function(event) {
        //another content
    },    
    contentAdded: function(content) {
        if (content.view == null) {
            var template_name;              
            switch(content.get("modelName")){   
                case 'home': template_name = 'home'; break;  
                case 'contact': template_name = 'contact'; break; 
            }                                       
            content.view = new ContentView({
                              model: content, template: //template
                     });
            $(".box").empty();    
            //render template                                               
            }       
        },              
});
```

When `#addContact` is clicked, `.box`is replaced for "another content". The problem is the next: If after `#addHome`is clicked, "another content" is replaced for plugin content but this content isn't correct because is shows an additional content. I think, trash content.
How solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Any idea for this problem?

Comment: The code works correctly with another plugins